# Prove that if $a_n$ and $b_n$ are equivalent Cauchy sequences as well as $b_n$ and $c_n$, then $a_n$ and $c_n$ are equivalent Cauchy sequences.

Tags: sequences-and-series, solution-verification, bounded-variation

Prove that if $a_{n}$ and $b_{n}$ are equivalent Cauchy sequences as well as $b_{n}$ and $c_{n}$, then $a_{n}$ and $c_{n}$ are equivalent Cauchy sequences.

**MY ATTEMPT**

Since $a_{n}$ and $b_{n}$ are equivalent, for every positve rational $\epsilon/2$, there is a natural number $N_{1}\geq 0$ such that $|a_{n} - b_{n}| \leq \epsilon/2$ for $n\geq N_{1}$. Similarly, there is a natural number $N_{2}\geq0$ such that $|b_{n} - c_{n}|\leq \epsilon/2$ for every $n\geq N_{2}$. Consequently, for every positive rational $\epsilon$, there in an $N = \max\{N_{1},N_{2}\}$ such that
\begin{align*}
|a_{n} - c_{n}| = |(a_{n} - b_{n}) - (b_{n} - c_{n})| \leq |a_{n} - b_{n}| + |b_{n} - c_{n}| \leq \epsilon/2 + \epsilon/2 = \epsilon
\end{align*}
for every $n\geq N$, and we are done.

Any comments or contributions to my attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is fine.

My only comment is that
you do what I call
"epsilon fiddling".
In other words,
to make your final bound
exactly $\epsilon$,
you use some multiple of
$\epsilon$ in your proof
so the final total
is exactly $\epsilon$.

I prefer to just use
$\epsilon$ at each stage
and them combine them.
In this case,
if the bound in each case is $\epsilon$,
the resulting bound is
$2\epsilon$.

As far as I am concerned,
any reasonable function of $\epsilon$
is good enough.